# nginx "fastcgi_cache_valid 404" not working

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, cache, fastcgi

I am doing simple caching with nginx. It works fine for 200 responses, but 404 responses do not "hit" the cache logic for some reason, and I do not understand why.

What I mean by "doesn't hit the cache logic", is based on my `add_header X-Cached`. This header doesn't appear at all if it's a 404 response.

404 response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2016 09:54:34 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 55
< Connection: keep-alive
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
```

200 response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2016 09:54:56 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 1186
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=5hq364dphuo8ka26sbcadiak74; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< X-Cached: MISS
```

Relevant nginx config:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

    fastcgi_cache_key $request_uri?$is_args$args;
    fastcgi_cache CACHENAME;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 90d;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 404 365d;
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_404 http_500;

    fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Set-Cookie Expires X-Accel-Expires Vary;

    add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;
}
```

My application is a REST API, so the response of 404 is just saying that the route returned false response.  I *want* this response cached.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: [`add_hader`](http://nginx.org/r/add_header). You should use `always` flag

Comment: @AlexeyTen aha, great, so it actually *has* been hitting cache properly, it just didn't say. Not sure how I missed that, so thanks much! Please comment it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexey mentioned that I was missing the `always` flag for my [`add_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) directive.

> `add_header` adds the specified field to a response header *provided that the response code equals 200, 201, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, or 307.*

As my application responded 404, it was still hitting nginx's cache properly, but add_header was never sent as a result.